# Splitting foreach in a table

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5.2

As of right now my table looks like this:

[image]

But I want to split the foreach to have it look something like this
[image]

Is possible to do this?

And this is the foreach:

```
@foreach (var date in ViewBag.MissingDays)
{
  var isoDate = date.ToString("yy-MM-dd");
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="javascript:SetDate('@isoDate');">@isoDate</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
}
```

Comment: Of course. What have you tried?

Comment: Questions without code snippets attracts vague answers.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Been trying the .split but for what I know that will split the string after the character is displayed, etc split after ' ' but I want it to split after 5 entries.

Comment: @ShrinivasShukla not much to show, but updated the post with the foreach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code to generate rows containing 9 columns

```
@{var counter = 1; }
<tr>
  @foreach (var date in ViewBag.MissingDays)
  {
    var isoDate = date.ToString("yy-MM-dd");
    <td><a href="javascript:SetDate('@isoDate');">@isoDate</a></td>
    if (counter % 9 == 0)
    {
      @:</tr><tr> // end current row and begin new one
    }
    counter++;
  }
</tr>
```

Comment: Pretty interesting solution, I've never came across ' @: ' before.

Comment: Without it you would get an exception. It a way of mixing plain text (the html) inside a razor code block