# split table inside foreach at x row

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

Inside my table I have 9 rows which I render using foreach loop inside razor view.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>a</th>
    <th>b</th>
    <th>c</th>
  </tr>
  @{ foreach(var item in Model.SomeProperties){
  <tr>
    <td>@item.a</td>
    <td>@item.b</td>
    <td>@item.c</td>
  </tr>
  } }
</table>
```

how can I split this at fifth row to be rendered like

```
a    f
b    g
c    h
d    x
e
```

instead of

```
a
b
c
..
x
```

Comment: try to use a variable which counts until 5. If the variable is 5 split the table and set it to 0 again.

Comment: Probably easiest to use a view model with 2 collection properties (the first 5 and the last 4) and just use loops on each

Comment: You can also use the technique described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31872944/splitting-foreach-in-a-table/31873791#31873791)

Comment: each your `item` have different propery? I mean `item.a`, `item.b`? Or your item have some kind of `value` property?

Comment: @teo van kot it doesn't matter really. Just as an example of some data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way how you can group your table that i ever found is use linq `GroupBy`

```
<table>
   @{
     foreach(var itemGroup in Model.SomeProperties
               .Select((e, i) => new { Item = e, Grouping = (i / 2) })
               .GroupBy(e => e.Grouping))
     {
        <tr>
           @foreach (var item in itemGroup.Select(x => x.Item))
           {
             <td>@item.value</td>   
           }      
        </tr>
     }
   }
</table>
```

But all your `item` should have the same `value` property to access your value.

With this technique now you can easily manipulate with `Grouping = (i / 2)` line to define how much values will be in your row.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<table>
    @{
        var count = 0;
        foreach(var item in Model.SomeProperties){
            if(count%5 == 0)
            {
                @Html.Raw("<tr><td><table>")
            }
            <tr>
                <td>@item.a</td>
                <td>@item.b</td>
                <td>@item.c</td>            
            </tr>
            if(count%5 == 4)
            {
                @Html.Raw("</td></tr></table>")
            }
            count++;
        }
    }
</table>
```

It will generate a new column, in the master table, each time you reach 5 lines.